# ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirerjs

I'm trying to use the command node index.js within the terminal to bring up the prompts I made and keep running into several errors, I looked them up on here seemingly fixed it and got another error. Maybe someone can point it out so I can save some time hopefully.. If you need more code details let me know.

Here is the ERROR in the terminal

```
$ node index.js
file:///C:/Users/Owner/bootcamp/homework/10-team-profile-generator/index.js:2
const fs = require('fs');
           ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\Owner\bootcamp\homework\10-team-profile-generator\package.json' 
contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS 
script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.  
    at ←[90mfile:///C:/Users/Owner/bootcamp/homework/10-team-profile-generator/←[39mindex.js:2:12
←[90m    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)←[39m
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
←[90m    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)←[39m
←[90m    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)←[39m
←[90m    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)←[39m
```

INDEX.JS

```
// node modules
const fs = require('fs');
const inquirer = require('inquirer')
const generateTeam = require("./src/template.js");

// lib modules
const Engineer = require("./lib/employee");
const Intern = require("./lib/intern");
const Manager = require("./lib/manager");

// Array for answers to questions
const newStaffMemberData = [];

// Array object questions asked in CLI to user
const questions = async () => {
  const answers = await inquirer
    .prompt([
      {
        type: "input",
        message: "What is your name?",
        name: "name",
      },
      {
        type: "input",
        message: "What is your ID number?",
        name: "id",
      },
      {
        type: "input",
        message: "What is your email?",
        name: "email",
      },
      {
        type: "list",
        message: "What is your role?",
        name: "role",
        choices: ["Engineer", "Intern", "Manager"],
      },
    ])


    
    //  console.log(answers);
      // if manager selected, answer these specific question
      if (answers.role === "Manager") {
        const managerAns = await inquirer
          .prompt([
            {
              type: "input",
              message: "What is your office number",
              name: "officeNumber",
            },
          ])
          const newManager = new Manager(
            answers.name,
            answers.id,
            answers.email,
            managerAns.officeNo
          );
          newStaffMemberData.push(newManager);
          
        // if engineer selected answer these set of questions
      } else if (answers.role === "Engineer") {
        const githubAns = await inquirer
          .prompt([
            {
              type: "input",
              message: "What is your GitHub user name?",
              name: "github",
            }
          ])
            const newEngineer = new Engineer(
              answers.name,
              answers.id,
              answers.email,
              githubAns.github
            );
            newStaffMemberData.push(newEngineer);
          
        // if intern selected answer these set of questions
      } else if (answers.role === "Intern") {
        const internAns = await inquirer
          .prompt([
            {
              type: "input",
              message: "What university did you attend?",
              name: "school",
            },
          ])
          
          const newIntern = new Intern(
            answers.name,
            answers.id,
            answers.email,
            internAns.school
          );
          newStaffMemberData.push(newIntern);          
      } 

}; //end of questions function

async function promptQuestions() {
  await questions()
    
  
  const addMemberAns = await inquirer
    .prompt([
      {
        name:'addMember',
        type: 'list',
        choices: ['Add a new member', 'Create team'],
        message: "What would you like to do next?"
      }
    ])

    if (addMemberAns.addMember === 'Add a new member') {
      return promptQuestions()
    }
    return createTeam();
}  

promptQuestions();

function createTeam () {
  console.log("new guy", newStaffMemberData)
  fs.writeFileSync(
    "./output/index.html",
    generateTeam(newStaffMemberData),
    "utf-8"
  );
}
```

Comment: * I tried renaming like it said and it threw another error.

Comment: Ditch the `require` and use `import`. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

do you have this line on your package.json ?

```
"type": "module"
```

if so, remove it and you can use require, but you'll get this error I believe:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/flaalf/self/sandbox/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js from /home/flaalf/self/sandbox/index.js not supported.
> Instead change the require of inquirer.js in /home/flaalf/self/sandbox/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

which I think it's related to the fact that The current version of inquirer is ONLY compatible with an ESM import (using import), not from CommonJS modules using require().

**UPDATE**:

leave the

```
"type": "module"
```

on you package.json and change the require for imports

instead of

```
const fs = require("fs")
const inquirer = require("inquirer")
```

change it to

```
import fs from "fs";
import inquirer from "inquirer";
```

Comment: Okay, so I did have that in my package.json, how do I change the require for imports? (sorry I just started coding last month and fairly new!)

Comment: instead of const fs = require("fs"); use import fs from "fs", and same example for inquirer

Comment: I put 
import fs from'fs';
import inquirer from'inquirer';
const generateTeam = require("./src/template.js");

Comment: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\Owner\bootcamp\homework\10-team-profile-generator\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/Owner/bootcamp/homework/10-team-profile-generator/index.js:4:22

Comment: when I change it I get a throw err;

Comment: require and import are 2 ~same way to load a module, change all the lines with a require, to somenthing with the form of ```import X from "module-name"```

Answer (score 0):

You may need just to add

> require.js

You can download it [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html)